# Python venv inside symlinked directory fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I just ran across this issue.

```
$ mkdir test
$ python3 -m venv test     -> is successful
$ rm -rf test
$ mkdir test
$ ln -s test/ test1
$ python3 -m venv test1
Error: Unable to create directory '#EDITED#/test1'
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Why do you need this to work? It's unable to create the directory because you've already created it.

Comment: @AKX It involves a scenario with qemu and a 9P mount where the permissions on the folder where the venv should be are weird. Basically, I can create a folder but can't write into it. So I was thinking of this as a workaround. The actual venv folder would be on a path where I have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, this is expected behaviour.Python's `venv` module has difficulties with symbolic links in some scenarios.

To make it work, you should create the directory `test1` directly, without using a symbolic link.

If you want both `test` and `test1`  to have separate virtual environments, you can do so like this:

```
mkdir test
python3 -m venv test/venv

mkdir test1
python3 -m venv test1/venv
```

This way, each directory (`test and test1`) will have its own separate virtual environment.

Hope this helps ans solves the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "trouble" as much as it refuses to go through the trouble of resolving links to see if they lead to a directory.

Comment: @keithpjolley - Yes, its not trouble but more of issues or difficulties sometimes, not everytime.

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv` (`pip install -U virtualenv`) works:

```bash
$ mkdir test
$ ln -s test/ test1

$ virtualenv test1
created virtual environment CPython2.7.18.final.0-64 in 114ms
  creator CPython2Posix(dest=/home/phd/tmp/test, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, wheel=bundle, setuptools=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/phd/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.37.1
  activators NushellActivator,PythonActivator,FishActivator,CShellActivator,PowerShellActivator,BashActivator

$ ls -lAF test
total 20
drwx------ 2 phd phd 4096 Sep 26 14:09 bin/
-rw------- 1 phd phd   40 Sep 26 14:09 .gitignore
drwx------ 2 phd phd 4096 Sep 26 14:09 include/
drwx------ 3 phd phd 4096 Sep 26 14:09 lib/
-rw------- 1 phd phd  253 Sep 26 14:09 pyvenv.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Isn't virtualenv at risk of being deprecated? I think I read it predates venv and the latter is meant to replace it.

Comment: @LouisNichols No, it's currently being maintained as a separate project (and it's much faster than `venv`, for one).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. From `venv/__main__.py`:

```
try:
    main()
    rc = 0
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: %s' % e, file=sys.stderr)
```

This is what is printing the message.  From `venv/__init__.py` the function to create the directory is:

```
        def create_if_needed(d):
            if not os.path.exists(d):
                os.makedirs(d)
            elif os.path.islink(d) or os.path.isfile(d):
                raise ValueError('Unable to create directory %r' % d)
```

Here, `not exists(d)` is false and `islink(d)` is true thus the `ValueError()` is raised.

You can reverse the order and accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
❯ python3 -m venv test
❯ ln -s test test1
❯ . test1/bin/activate
❯ which python3
/tmp/test/bin/python3
```

Notice that the path resolves to the original path because this is embedded in the `activate` script.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Unfortunately, the reverse order doesn't work in my case (see my comment to my original post), so I'll have to think of something else.